# Calling one components method from another component via its instance not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to call one components method from another component. I have created the instance of that component and calling its method but it doesn't seem firing. If you see below I am calling this.termComponent.getTermsDetails();

Comp 1

```
 saveFundClass() {
             this.termsService.createFundClass(this.FundClass).then((result ) => {
                if (result) {
                     this.termComponent = new TermsComponent(this.termsService);
                    this.notify.success('Fund Class Successfully Created');
                    this.termComponent.getTermsDetails();
                }
            }) .catch(err => {
                if (err.status === 409) {
                    this.notify.error('Fund Class with same name already exist for the given fund');
                } else if (err.status === 400) {
                    this.notify.error('Please ensure the LegalFundClass and Description are entered before saving');
                } else {
                    this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While adding Classification Overrides Details');
                }
            });
    }
```

Component 2

```
constructor(private termsService: TermsService) { }

public getTermsDetails() {
    if (this.ManagerStrategyId != null) {
        this.termsService.getTermsDetails(this.ManagerStrategyId).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.TermDetails = data;
            this.OriginalList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
            this.LegalFundClasses = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel;
            this.FundTerms = this.TermDetails.FundTermsViewModel;
            this.Funds = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.Funds;
            this.FundClassType = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.FundClassType;
            this.FirmFunds = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.FirmFunds;

            this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel.forEach(funDetail=> {
                funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel = funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel
                    .reduce((prev, next) => prev = prev.concat(next), [])
                    .filter(obj => obj.InvestedAmount !== null);
            });

           this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel = this.TermDetails
                                                                                         .LegalFundClassViewModel
                                                                                         .LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel
                                                                                         .filter(obj => obj.InvestmentStatusId === 1);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's not the same instance, if you write `new XComponent()` this is a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Viewchild`

Assuming `TermComponent` is your child component

**Comp 1**

TS:

```
@ViewChild('termComponent') termComponent: TermComponent;
```

`this.termComponent.getTermsDetails();`

HTML:

```
<child-component #termComponent></child-component>
```

Comment: termcomponent is not child of component1

Comment: termcompoent is the parent of this component1's parent

Comment: Okay... From which component you want to call function of which another component? I got confused

Comment: Component 2 here in the example is the termscomponent which is parent component. I need to call the method of this component from its child's child. Component 1 here is its child's child

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, the component structure as

`TermComponent -> ParentComponent -> Component1`

To invoke the method of TermComponent from Component1, you can do either of the following,

1. Emit event from Component1 which intern emit another event in ParentComponent which will end up in invoking the method of TermComponent.
2. You can use ngRx/store for state management. You can subscribe for the state changes in TermComponent and once the state change, you can invoke the method.

Comment: Its TermComponent - > child component -> its child component. I am trying to call method of the parent from its grandchild child component